# Intl.NumberFormat reformatting the currencySymbol

Tags: javascript, currency, number-formatting

I'm using JS' [Intl.Numberformat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) function, but is there a way I can replace the output that's now:
`ANG12.45`
Format to: `fl. 12.45`
So replace the default `currencyDisplay` to a custom naming including a space between the symbol and value?

```
value = parseFloat(value);
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'ANG', 
    currencyDisplay: 'symbol',
    minimumFractionDigits: 2
});
return formatter.format(value);
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Yes: ```return formatter.format(value).replace("ANG", "ƒ ");```

Comment: Then you need to accept [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
return formatter.format(value).replace("ANG", "ƒ ");
```

Answer (score 0):

This can not be done with the `Intl.NumberFormat` object, because the value of the "currency" parameter must be in [ISO 4217 currency codes list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217) and there is no "FL" there.

Comment: The link "ISO 4217 currency codes list " is not redirecting correctly. Please edit it :)

Comment: @Lahcen - link updated ... better late than never I guess :) - thanks for pointing it out.